# npm run build production does not distribute the production

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have a problem with my Angular project. Especially on the build of the project.

When I build my Angular poject with

```
ng build
```

it creates the dist-folder with the correct build. When I use the following command:

```
ng build --prod
```

it creates the production build (correct)

When I use NPM (used by build server) I use this:

```
run build
```

But I want the production build. Whatever I do, it doesn't work locally or on the buildserver. I used these:

```
npm run build --prod
npm run build --target=production
npm run build --environment=prod
npm run build --environment=production
npm run build --env=production
npm run build --env=prod
npm run build *projectname* --environment=production
npm run build *projectname* --env=production
npm run build *projectname* production
```

And probably a lot more. It just does not build the production!

I have a environment.prod.ts (`production = true`). It is set in the Angular.json. I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what `npm run build` shows in console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`npm run build` should have the script in the `package.json`
have a look there and maybe add the line in the scripts

```
{
...
 scripts: {
    "build": "ng build --prod"
 },
...
}
```

this should do the trick

Comment: Yup, that is it. I have made on change though: I added "build_prod" with the command "ng build --prod". This way I can also build for local. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

You could also use `--` to separate the params passed to npm command itself and params passed to your script.
So the correct syntax for your case would be:

```
npm run build -- --prod
```

Comment: thankyou for this. it works

Comment: This syntax is usual in the command-line world. In this case, `--` separates the command-line options between the first command `npm` where their arguments are `run build` and the second command `ng` (see package.json) where its argument is `--prod`. So, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is update the build script in the `package.json` as

```
scripts:{
   "build": "npm run ng build --",
   "ng": "ng"
}
```

`--` allows you to pass arguments to a script.

Then you can pass the arguments to `ng build` like `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your environment is `production`:

```
npm run build -- --configuration=production
```

or this if it's `prod`:

```
npm run build -- --configuration=prod
```

If you don't specify the "configuration" parameter name you may see this error:

```
npm run build -- --prod
```

> Error: Unknown argument: prod

```
npm run build -- --production
```

> Error: Unknown argument: production