# Angular is running in development mode when building as production

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, environment-variables

I have an Angular application that I want to run in `prodMode` in my environments in Azure. The app is built and run as a Docker container in Azure with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-stretch as build-deps

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY MyApp/package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY MyApp/src ./src
COPY MyApp/ts*.json ./
COPY MyApp/angular.json ./
RUN npm run build --configuration=production

FROM nginx:1.23-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY MyApp/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/dist/myapp .

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

I have three environment files:

`environment.ts`:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    env: {
      originMyAppBackend: string;
    };
  }
}

import { environment } from './environment.production';
environment.production = false;
export { environment };
```

`environment.productions.ts`:

```js
const originMyAppBackend = window['env']['originMyAppBackend'];

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url: {
    internalApiPath: '/api/internal/',
    openApiPath: '/api/open/v1/',
    apiBaseUrl: `${originMyAppBackend}`,
  },
};
```

And `environment.development.ts`:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url: {
    internalApiPath: 'NA',
    openApiPath: 'NA',
    apiBaseUrl: 'NA',
  },
};
```

And relevant part of `angular.json`:

```json
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/jsonstat-toolkit/iife.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "20kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
      }
```

And then in `main.ts`, `enableProdMode()` should be called:

```js
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

However even though the `Dockerfile` specifies to build with `configuration=production` and `angular.json` specifies to replace the environment file with the production environment file, the console still prints "Angular is running in development mode" in the Azure environment. How can I make my app run in `prodMode`?

I suspect setting `environment.production=true` in `environment.ts` would solve it (although not certain), but that would also cause the app to run in `prodMode` locally, which I don't want.

EDIT: I tried changing `environment.production=true` in `environment.ts`, but the console still logs "Angular is running in development mode".

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate, but [npm run build production does not distribute the production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812626/npm-run-build-production-does-not-distribute-the-production) looks to have the same base issue. Instead of `npm run build --configuration=production`, try `npm run build -- --prod`.

Comment: I think the issue is that `--configuration=production` is being passed as an argument to `npm run` rather than to the internal `ng build` command. Adding an extra `--` allows the argument to apply to the expected command. `-- --configuration=production` should also work if you prefer.

Comment: This might work, however when adding the `--` I get the error `#16 29.03 Error: src/environments/environment.production.ts:1:36 - error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
#16 29.03
#16 29.03 1 const originAllvisBackend = window['env']['originMyAppBackend'];` which is the first line in `environment.productions.ts`. So it implies that it actually tries using the correct env file, but fails reading the environment variable which is set in Azure. @DM

Comment: That sounds like a TypeScript issue during build. Have you tried either moving the global definition to the production configuration file or manually typing that line in the production configuration file? Something like `(window['env'] as unknown as { originMyAppBackend: string }).originMyAppBackend;`